# Is it better to use street view panorama in Google map v3 with javaScript api than using native android map v2

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

am new to android development. I was working on android map v2 and street view panorama. I discovered that I can not query street view panorama to know if it is available in the typed location. Is it advisable to switch over to titanium appcelerator,instead of native android, since map v3 is only available in JavaScript. What is the best thing to do now. Am very new to programming.

Comment: Depending on your app requirements, you may not use Titanium Appcelerator, simply a WebView. But i recommend to use native Google Maps for Android, the performance is much better, among other reasons

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer webo80.If i use WebView,will i be able to add map v3 to the WebView? with all its fantastic features. All I want is to add map v3 to my android app.For a new beginner like me, it will be a significant motivation.